# I'm trying to find a way to let someone add multiple items to their steam cart through a link

Tags: javascript, store, google-docs, cart, steam

I have created a google document with a list of all DLC for a game, and I would like to let them add it all quickly to their cart (as there is a lot).

The problem is that steam's DLC system sucks, so you have to juggle between cart and store each time you add something. As far as I know, steam uses a javascript function called `addToCart(appID)`, where `appID` would be something like 545100 and the link for that page would be `store.steampowered.com/app/545100`.

Link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hqr9a2zQIB0UZH1oVZfhmL24YBg_eIOD1PayrRh8l3M

Also, this is my first post so hello stack overflow! Been using it for a couple years but have never had to ask a question.

Comment: How do you expect to call JavaScript on Steam's page? That is the definition of a XSS vulnerability. Perhaps you've left out an important detail regarding how you intend to accomplish this?

Comment: That is what I'm asking, if there is a way to call a javascript function on another page. Even if it opens a new tab and then calls the function on that tab without switching over to it

Comment: Then no, what you're asking for is an XSS vulnerability on Steam.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyways! Closing thread.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Nathan K 2.

> Then no, what you're asking for is an XSS vulnerability on Steam. – Nathan K